# Scala IDE supporting autocompletion and syntax highlighting

Tags: scala, ide

I'm looking for a good Scala IDE.

I tried the Eclipse (Some time ago) and IntelliJ Idea (In these days) plugins but I am somehow dissatisfied by both of them. The first it was pretty slow and unstable, while I don't like too much IntelliJ Idea's interface.

Is there any alternative available?

I will work with a SBT project and what I am looking for is mainly syntax highlighting, autocompletion. It would be nice to have partial compilation of the source code as I am not used to Scala syntax and it would help me find errors as soon as I write them.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419207/which-is-the-best-ide-for-scala-development

Comment: I personally use Scala IDE for Eclipse, which I describe as "it's not just good, it's good enough." Which is to say I don't think it's that great, but it seems to be the best IDE available, and I'm familiar with Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Scala IDE for Eclipse](http://www.scala-ide.org) is under active development and evolving rapidly. You should give it a try now (I don't know what 'some time ago' means, but if it's more than 6 months you might be pleasantly surprised). Granted, I am biased since I am a committer.

Comment: The Scala IDE is really nice. A few rough edges, but a huge win overall. I use some features all the time, like hovering over a val to see what type's been inferred.

Comment: Especially now that the 2.1 M2 release is out, Scala IDE for Eclipse is really an option.

Answer (score 7):

IMHO InteliJ is the best IDE for Scala at the moment. First I had also some problems with the different interface compared with Eclipse. But in the end you profite from the whole package included with IntelliJ. There is also an active scala plugin development.

Comment: Maybe I have to get used to the different interface. So far I simply waste lot of time trying to find out how to do things

Answer (score 6):

What I like to do is split my terminal once horizontally, and then split the bottom pane once vertically.

In the top pane I have `vim` (`emacs` works too if you're an `emacs` person) with the NERDTree plugin (acts like the project folder/file browser in text editors). On the bottom left I have SBT continuous compilation (`sbt ~compile`). I use the bottom right pane to actually run code (tests, etc.).

Regarding auto-completion, you can try something like the Snipmate plugin for `vim`.

Also, as stated by Ivan, if you end up using `emacs` ENSIME seems to be widely liked - unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an ENSIME port for `vim` yet, at least to my knowledge.

With this setup, I edit in the top pane, and once I save a file, I get near immediate feedback by just glancing on the bottom left and know when I typo'ed something, or maybe my code is just plain wrong, stuff like that.

On a slightly related note, I used to use IDE's but they got too messy for my taste (back then I was writing C and C++) so I moved to just a text editor (e.g. Chocolat, Sublime Text 2) and used a terminal, and that was fine for me for about a year. Then this summer I really sat down and tried going `vim` only and I can honestly say I'm much more productive in my all terminal setup than what I was before. Just my 2 cents.

This all also has the added benefit of working on remote servers as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could try ENSIME for emacs. You can also use it with jEdit, Sublime Text 2, and probably more.

Personally I use Scala IDE 2.1 (for eclipse). It is a lot faster now, and it has gotten to the point where I actually want to use it, after being in a similar situation to you.

Comment: I'll have a look at the new version of Scala IDE